# iFrames not responsive side by side (inline block breaking when screen goes small)

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am using two `iframes` and I have removed any `padding` or `margin` from my code. They both break (they are no longer aligned) when the screen goes small and I still cannot find out why.

```css
body{
    background:#0d3852;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
iframe{
    background:#ccc;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.box { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
    width:49.77%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="box">
                <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/user/radomer/playlist/4S4lTBokwOjIvEHkz3klTj" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/user/radomer/playlist/4S4lTBokwOjIvEHkz3klTj" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making it float will fix the problem. Please refer style updates of **.box** rule set..

```css
body{
    background:#0d3852;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
iframe{
    background:#ccc;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.box { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float : left;
    width:50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="box">
                <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/user/radomer/playlist/4S4lTBokwOjIvEHkz3klTj" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <iframe src="https://www.sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html
```

Comment: Yeah. I was curious why the previous version did not work. With normal divs instead of iframes, it does work. This one works for the iframes too.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:flex;` instead of `display:inline-block;`

```css
body {
  background: #0d3852;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

iframe {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 49.77%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/user/radomer/playlist/4S4lTBokwOjIvEHkz3klTj" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/user/radomer/playlist/4S4lTBokwOjIvEHkz3klTj" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Still cannot understand why it didn't work for me. Save the snippet in an HTML file and you will probably get the same.